# Copy from HTML div without copying the formatting style

Tags: html, richtext

I have a div which has a bunch of styling (`font-family`, `font-size`, `background-color`, etc.) and I'd like to be able to copy text from it, and paste it into a rich text editor (Google Docs or Gmail for eg.) without it pasting the styles.

I know I can use the "paste without formatting" or equivalent option, but I'd like to know if there's a clean way to disable copying the formatting at all on the webpage itself, because I only care about the text.

To test: run this snippet, copy the styled text, and paste it into a [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/create).

```html
<div style="background-color: orange">
Copy me!
</div>
```

Comment: Textareas have no formatting; they're plain text only. Post a [mcve] showing us what you're dealing with please

Comment: My bad. it was a div, I got confused with my own markup. Added a reproducible example though!